# Sorting Airplane Seats And Their Passengers By Seat Order

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

I am aware of the homework policy and rest assured that I have put copious amounts of my own time into this assignment and I am not looking for someone to simply do my work for me.

I am a beginning Computer Science major with no programming experience before this class (it is all about C programming), outside of a small amount of website development when I was younger. I'm thoroughly enjoying the curriculum and have found myself to have a better understanding than most others in my class so far, but this assignment has me stumped.

The assignment is to read in a text file of passenger names (first and last initial), seats (A1, B1, C1, D1, A2, etc.), and ticket prices. The output is specified to be a table of passengers and their seats sorted by seat order, and I also have to print the minimum and maximum ticket prices along with the owner of each ticket, along with the average of all ticket prices. My arrays are all reading in correctly, and the minimum, maximum, and average ticket prices were all easy to find. My problem is the sorting. We were introduced to arrays a couple weeks ago and this is our first time doing any sorting. We are supposed to use a bubble sort, and while I think I gather how to use a bubble sort, it's not working in my program (so obviously I don't really know how to use it). I have tried several different things, and sometimes a few seats/names will switch around (never the way I want them to) and sometimes nothing will happen at all.

Anyway, TL;DR: New to programming, not trying to get homework done for me, need to bubble sort airplane passengers and seats by seat order (A1, B1, C1, D1, A2, etc). Thanks in advance for any help.

My input looks like this:

A Z A1 555.55
repeat with different initials, seats, and prices however many times the user sees fit.

I have a 1D character array for the columns(A - D), a 1D integer array for rows (1 to maximum integer), 1D float array for prices, and 2D array for name initals.

Here's the function to read in the arrays:

```
void read_Arrays(char seat_cols[], int seat_rows[], char name[][LAST], float price[])
{
int i, j;

    for(i = 0; i < SIZE; i++)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < LAST; j++)
        {
            scanf(" %c", &name[i][j]);
        }  
        scanf(" %c %d %f ", &seat_cols[i], &seat_rows[i], &price[i]);
    }
}
```

Here's the sort. The way we were shown to do it was with a 'for' loop nested within a 'do while':

```
do
{
    flag = 0;
    for(i=0; i < ROWSIZE-1; i++)   
    {

        if(seat_rows[i] > seat_rows[i+1])
        {
            //swap first initial
            tempName = name[i][0];
            name[i][0] = name [i+1][0];
            name[i+1][0] = tempName;

            /*swap last initial*/
            tempName = name[i][1];
            name[i][1] = name [i+1][1];
            name[i+1][1] = tempName;

            //swap seat_cols
            tempName = seat_cols[i];
            seat_cols[i] = seat_cols[i+1];
            seat_cols[i+1] = tempName;

            //swap seat_rows
            temp = seat_rows[i];
            seat_rows[i] = seat_rows[i+1];
            seat_rows[i+1] = temp;

            //flag
            flag = 1;
        }//end if

    }//end for

}while(flag == 1);
```

UPDATE:  Thanks for the information so far, and it's good to know I should answer my own questions instead of editing the original. However, It won't let me answer my own question at this time due to lack of reputation points, so I'm posting the update here.

The input file:

S J  D2   579.12

S G  A4   176.98

B B  B3   244.78

A M  C9   337.15

B C  A6   444.89

J B  B2   891.55

M M  D7   478.16

C H  B1   119.63

W W  A8   342.93

L R  C5   588.22

The output:

B1 CH

B2 JB

D2 SJ

B3 BB

A4 SG

C5 LR

A6 BC

D7 MM

A8 WW

C9 AM

The average ticket price is 420.34.

The minimum ticket price is 119.63 and the owner is CH.

The maximum ticket price is 891.55 and the owner is JB.

Disregard the ticket prices, those are working properly.  I see that the row numbers are sorted, and the names are still associated with their correct seats, but the columns are all over the place.

Here is the updated sort:

```
do
{
    flag = 0;
    for(i=0; i < SIZE-1; i++)   
    {

        if(seat_rows[i] > seat_rows[i+1])
        {
            //swap first initial
            tempName = name[i][0];
            name[i][0] = name [i+1][0];
            name[i+1][0] = tempName;

            /*swap last initial*/
            tempName = name[i][1];
            name[i][1] = name[i+1][1];
            name[i+1][1] = tempName;

            //swap seat_cols
            tempName = seat_cols[i];
            seat_cols[i] = seat_cols[i+1];
            seat_cols[i+1] = tempName;

            //swap seat_rows
            temp = seat_rows[i];
            seat_rows[i] = seat_rows[i+1];
            seat_rows[i+1] = temp;

            //swap prices
            temp2 = price[i];
            price[i] = price[i+1];
            price[i+1] = temp2;

            //flag
            flag = 1;
        }//end if

        if(seat_rows[i] == seat_rows[i+1])
        {
            if(seat_cols[i] > seat_cols[i+1])
            {
                //swap first initial
                tempName = name[i][0];
                name[i][0] = name [i+1][0];
                name[i+1][0] = tempName;

                /*swap last initial*/
                tempName = name[i][1];
                name[i][1] = name[i+1][1];
                name[i+1][1] = tempName;

                //swap seat_cols
                tempCol = seat_cols[i];
                seat_cols[i] = seat_cols[i+1];
                seat_cols[i+1] = tempCol;

                //swap seat_rows
                temp = seat_rows[i];
                seat_rows[i] = seat_rows[i+1];
                seat_rows[i+1] = temp;

                //swap prices
                temp2 = price[i];
                price[i] = price[i+1];
                price[i+1] = temp2;

                //flag
                flag = 1;
            }
        }
    }//end for
}while(flag == 1);
```

Comment: You've explained your background, posted your assignment, dumped some code, correctly formatted it. All relatively good so far. The only thing that's missing is an actual question. What seems to be the problem with the code you've posted? What question are you asking?

Comment: After correcting the careless mistake of having seat_cols and seat_rows sorted twice, the output is sorted but not in the order I need them to be.  The row numbers (1-10) are all fine, but the column letters (A through D) are in no discernible order and the names are no longer assigned to their original seats.

Comment: Try developing just a bubble sort for some pre-defined data, as a test-benched program.  Once you get bubble sort to work in a throw-away program then copy it over to your lab code and re-fit to work with the current code.

Comment: Some tips. Currently you have all your sort logic duplicated twice. It would be better to decide whether or not you want to sort, storing that decision in a variable if necessary; and then just have the sorting code once.  Secondly, have you learned about `struct` yet? If so, then placing each person's details in a struct means you will only need one "swap" - the whole struct - rather than five swaps.

Comment: Actually, the code is working perfectly.  The reason it looks strange is because you are sorting by column first and then by row.  That matches the original specification of " seat order (A1, B1, C1, D1, A2, etc).", but does look a little strange when the input doesn't have a complete set of columns (ABCD) for each row.

Comment: OK, thanks again.  I'll mess around with the code and see if I can get the output to be similar to the output of my first input file.  And I haven't yet learned about struct yet; I'm stuck using my basic knowledge of arrays and loops.  Also, I'll see about cleaning the sort algorithm up and getting rid of the duplicate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The comparison in your bubble sort only checks the `seat_rows`.  When `seat_rows` are equal, the `seat_cols` needs to be checked to determine whether a swap is needed.

Also note that the swap code needs to include the `price`, or the prices will get scrambled relative to the seat assignments.

Comment: Thanks a lot, that really helped out.  I should have seen that.

Comment: I made several adjustments to my code and with your help it worked for one of my input files (40 seats, A1-D10 all scrambled), however when I change the input to 10 seats (A3, D5, C2, D9, B8, A4, etc) the sort doesn't work.  I changed my defined constants appropriately but once again I'm failing to see the problem in the sort.

Comment: Hmm, well this raises many questions. What was the exact input array? What was the resulting output array? And what's the latest version of the code. Note: when providing code updates, it's best not to overwrite the original code in the question, because doing so invalidates any answers, e.g. that's why Mark withdrew his answer. The preferred way to post updated code is to answer your own question with the new code.  That way, people who see this question can see the original code, with any problems that it had, and the corrected code.  Hopefully, then they can apply that to their own problem.

Comment: Thank you, I didn't realize the effect of updates to the original question.  I posted my update below the original question, since answering my own questions at this point is not allowed.